# Unix shells: How to ensure command works against most common shells?

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

I have some java code which uses jsch to connect to our unix servers and run below command.

> ls -lt /tempdirectory/ grep -v '^do | grep "$"(date '+%b %e')" | head
> -1 | awk '{print %9}'

Above command shows all files in the /tempdirectory in long format (the first pipe removes directories). From the result it then filters for all files which were created today (I.e. it greps for "Oct 16").  Since I did ls -lt the files are ordered by time, so when I pipe against head -1 I will get the latest file today. And then the last pipe will print the filename out

On a normal putty terminal, once I switch to bash shell, and run above command, it will correctly print out the latest file today.

But the default shell seems to be Bourne (-sh) which the above command will fail (and hence my code will fail)

Is there a way to create above command that is safe for common shells? I think the main shells I've seen at work are:

Bourne (sh)
Bourne again (bash)
Korn (ksh)

Comment: Note that on modern systems, `sh` is not Bourne but POSIX sh. This 1992 standard (compared to 1970s Bourne) requires `$(...)` to be included. I would strongly disagree with any assertion that pre-POSIX Bourne is "common" in 2020.

Comment: The only operating system vendor I know to have shipped real Bourne in the last 20 years is Sun. Absolutely everyone else has been using a real POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Ah my OS is sunOS haha

Comment: There may also be a POSIX sh on the system. Something like `/usr/xpg/bin/sh`, I want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, I found the issue. Bourne cannot handle $(...) hence I needed to replace this with --> ` <--- (not the regular apostrophes)

Reference:
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/188983-syntax-error-line-24-unexpected.html

So the command becomes

> ls -lt /tempdirectory/ | grep -v '^d' | grep "`date '+%b %e'`" | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'

I dont whether this will work on many different shells but it seems to work on sh as well as bash

For some reason StackOverflow is not showing that apostrophe properly so I will clarify that I added the weird other apostrophe ` after the first double quote and before the last double quote in:

"{here}date '+%b %e'{here}"

(Also based on previous comments, it sounds like this is not just a matter of what shell you are using when determining command compatibility - your underlying OS may also have an impact. In my case, using uname -a shows i am using sunOS)

Answer (score 1):

This is where you should be using the `find(1)` command instead:

```
$ find /tmpdir -type f -ctime -1
```

gets all the files from `/tmpdir` created (ctime) today.

If you want all the files then you don't need any more modifiers. If you want to limit further, see the GNU Find manpage at https://linux.die.net/man/1/find.

The `find(1)` command is independent of which shell you have access to on the remote machine.

Comment: What is important is that the files are created from midnight today onwards. I had created test files and modified their dates using (touch -a -m -t 202010152359.59 test1.txt) and created edge cases like files created at 11:59pm and just after midnight as well as a file at 1am yesterday. It seems your command just finds all the files. I also tried replacing ctime with mtime but I can see it prints all files except for the file made 1am yesterday (I.e. it looks like it finds all files from last 24 hours as opposed to all files from midnight today)

Comment: I tried using that daystart parameter in your link but it seems to give a bad parameter option error when i try it in bash and bourne?

Comment: If you've got a reference file with appropriate timestamp, you can use `-cnewer /path/to/reference/file` to get everything createed after that file. Likewise for mtime (modified) and atime (access)

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have a reference file

Comment: You can create one with `touch`: `touch -t "$(date +"%Y%m%d0000")" ref_file`

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted

> ls -lt / grep -v '^do | grep "$"(date '+%b %e')" | head -1 |awk'{print %9}'

has syntax errors and cannot be run in any shell

Fixed it to

```
 ls -lt  /tempdirectory/ | grep -v '^d' | grep "$(date '+%b %e')" | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'
```

It is ANSI compatible and runs in `sh`, `bash` and `zsh` (what I have tested).

Comment: Hi sorry for syntax errors i was typing on my phone. The problem is when I run the command in sh it returns nothing (whereas in bash it does return today's file). From what I understand the issue seems to be coming from the grep date command. Even if I copy paste your answer straight into the console it will not work

Comment: If I enter: echo $(date '+%b %e') in sh I get syntax error: '(' unexpected. Whereas if I ran this in bash it would output the date as expected.

Comment: I searched the error and found that Bourne (sh) cannot handle $() hence I replaced this with `` (that weird other appostrophe). With this the entire command seems to now work in sh and bash. Although funnily enough now my jsch exec program is erroring with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: Found out my java error was failing for a different reason and not due to my command. Everything seems to work now ! Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, always copy paste code from command line, don't retype it.

Comment: @CaptainObv >Even if I copy paste your answer straight into the console it will not work. You did not tell us what system you are using. The command that I provided works correctly in Ubuntu, FreeBSD and MacOS.

Comment: Oh apologies. I thought only the shell mattered. How would you find out which version of unix you are using?

Comment: Different *nixes use different programs as /bin/sh. For Ubuntu this is `dash`, for FreeBSD `ash`, MacOS uses modified `bash`.
You can get the name of the OS with the command `uname -a`

Comment: According to uname -a, i have SunOS